# how to save the sweetalert DOM node value into database laravel?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, sweetalert

I want to have a sweet alert input(the  DOM node example)  to ask the user to enter a specific value.
Then I want to save the value into the database
PS: i'm working with Laravel
here's my code of sweetalert

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.servipopupmsg').click(function(e){
  var namefourn = $(this).find(".namefourn").text( );
  e.preventDefault();
  swal("are you sure you want to continue with "+namefourn+"?  ", {
  buttons: ["Cancel ", "confirm "],
}).then((result) => {
  if( result){
    console.log("User confirmed!" );
    swal("Taper Matricule Camion:", {
    content: "input",
    })
    .then((value) => {
    console.log("Value to check for valid matricule: "+ value );
      //the code that i'm asking about to check if the input  is valid(correct form
      //if yes insert the input into the database
    });
  }else{
    console.log( "User Not confirmed!" );
  }
})
})
});
</script>
```

This what I want to do:

1. **Ask user for input using the sweetalert DOM NODE**
2. **Take the input and check if it's valid**
3. **add the input into the right column in the data base**

I'm not sure if I've explained this correctly, but any ideas or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is your question though? What's not working? SO is not here to write code for you but to help you with your code

Comment: i used ajax to add the value but it didn't work for me